# Why datepicker is lost after window.print?

Tags: jquery, printing

I have to print part of my page by `window.print()`. Here is the code:

```
    function printDiv(divName) {
      var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
      var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
      document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
      window.print();
      document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
      }
```

I know that copy innerHTML and pasting it after print command can cause lost of event listener. But it can be overcome by a `$('body').on` attachment. But as I am novice to jQuery, I do not know how can I use this jquery on method in case of datepicker attachment. So, every time I print part of my web page using this type of JavaScript print method, datepicker is lost and it is not attaching in the desired input fields.

On my site, I click on the `#dob` or other input fields to see the workable datepicker. Then I press `Print` button and cancel or done the print job. After that you can see that there is no datepicker attached on click of `#dob` and other input fields of the table.

How to resolve this issue? Please don't recommend CSS print system, I have to use this method.

The code that is attaching the datepicker:

```
$('.ro').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  disabled:true
});




$('#dob, table.grid > tbody> tr > td > input[type="text"]').datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: '1900:2016'
    });

//$('#dob, table.grid > tbody> tr > td > input[type="text"]').change(function(){
   //updateTable($(this));
//});

$('body').on('change','#dob, table.grid > tbody> tr > td > input[type="text"]',function(){
   updateTable($(this));
});

function updateTable(select){
          if(select.attr("id") == "dob"){
            $('.ro').val('');
            var rowLen = $('table.grid > tbody >tr').length;
          }else{
            var rowLen=1;
          }

           var r = 0;
           var pr = 0;
           while(r<rowLen){
              if(select.attr("id") == "dob"){
                 var thisRow = $('table.grid > tbody > tr').eq(r+1);
              }else{
                 var thisRow = select.closest('tr');
              }


           var inputlen = thisRow.find('input[type="text"]').length;
           var inputIndex = thisRow.find(':input[type="text"]').index(this);
           var RowInput = thisRow.find('input[type="text"]');
           var RowSch =  thisRow.prev().find('input[type="text"]');
           var thisDate = select.datepicker('getDate');
           var vname = thisRow.prev().find('td:eq(0)').text();
           var pros = false;
           var thisCell = select.closest('td').index();

           for($i=inputIndex;$i<(inputlen-1);$i++){
             var c = RowSch.eq($i+1).attr('c');
             var d = parseInt(RowSch.eq($i+1).attr('d'),10);
             var a = parseInt(RowSch.eq($i+1).attr('a'),10);
             if(a==0){
               if($('#dob').datepicker('getDate')==null){
                 alert('Date of Birth is required for Schedule Date of Dose-'+($i+2)+' of '+vname+' !!');
                 break;
               }else{
                 thisDate=$('#dob').datepicker('getDate');
                 //alert('Datepicker date: '+thisDate);
                 pros=true;
               }
             }else if(a==99){
               //break;
               pros=false;
             }else{
                if(RowInput.eq(a-1).datepicker('getDate')!=null){
                   thisDate = RowInput.eq(a-1).datepicker('getDate');
                   pros = true;
                }else if(RowSch.eq(a-1).datepicker('getDate')!=null){
                   thisDate = RowSch.eq(a-1).datepicker('getDate');
                   pros = true;
                }else{
                   alert('Date of Dose-'+a+' is required for Schedule Date of Dose-'+($i+2)+' of '+vname+' !!');
                   pros = false;
                   break;
                }
             }



             if(pros){

                if (c == 'y') {
                   thisDate.setFullYear(thisDate.getFullYear() + d);
                }
                if (c == 'd') {
                    thisDate.setDate(thisDate.getDate() + d);
                }
                if (c == 'm') {
                    thisDate.setMonth(thisDate.getMonth() + d);
                }
                //thisDate.setDate(thisDate.getDate() + 30);
                RowSch.eq($i+1).datepicker('setDate', thisDate);
             }
            pr = pr+1;
           }
           r=r+2;

           //alert(thisDate.setDate(thisDate.getDate() + 30));
          }
}
```

Comment: why someone gives me downvote everytime even after my request? This is very pathetic.

Comment: Your replacing the innerHTML.  This is going to undo not only any bindings that you had, but any plugin initialization associated.  Instead of doing that, why not simply hide everything BUT what you want to print and then afterwards reshow it?

Comment: Open the content for print in a popup and print this instead

Comment: Andreas, I already mentioned that I have to use this method. Thankyou!

Comment: I've tidied up this question text in a number of ways (see the edit message). In particular I would ask that, in general, you do not add links to your own website to illustrate a problem. Once you have fixed it, people reading your question will no longer see what you wanted them to - and we want questions to last forever here. Thus it is very good practice to use screenshots and other in-question material to show what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re initialize your datepickers when you reset the content of the `body` tag. As when you will reset the `html` all the function bindings are lost.

```
function printDiv(divName) {
  var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
  // Reinitialize the datepicker here

  $('#dob, table.grid > tbody> tr > td > input[type="text"]').datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     yearRange: '1900:2016'
  });
}
```

Comment: please don't mind, would you plz show me, how can I reinitialize the datepicker in the point you mentioned? I am very new to jquery.

Comment: Can you post your current jquery code and they way you are setting up your datepicker?

Comment: sure, Please see my own answer to this question below.

Comment: I just have added it in my own answer, not in question.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid see the updated answer. And please add your code in your question.

Comment: void, I have followed your suggestion, but still it is not working. Please visit my site now to see the difference.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, try your solution but didn't work out.